# Why doesn't Chromium headless dump the DOM when I tell it to?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, headless

Here's exactly what I did:

1. I went to https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ and clicked the button.
2. I ran the file (oddly called chrome-win.exe instead of Chromium.exe).
3. I went to its install directory and opened a cmd.exe in there.
4. I ran the command:

   chrome.exe --headless --dump-dom "https://www.example.com/"

According to the manual, this is *supposed* to open that URL *headlessly* and dump the DOM as text after JavaScript has been executed, to the stdout, meaning the `cmd.exe` in this case.

***Problem: Nothing happens***. Literally no output at all. The only thing that I can tell that happens (and that was just out of pure coincidence) is that a file called `chrome_debug.txt` is created in the same directory, with this contents:
    [0712/065333.417:ERROR:browser_process_sub_thread.cc(203)] Waited 5 ms for network service

If I instead run the command:

```
chrome.exe "https://www.example.com/"
```

It opens the browser and goes to that URL (as expected). So it's not something fundamentally wrong with my Internet connection or computer.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem. On MACOSX the DOM is actually output but to the terminal. No amount of redirect (`1>` `2>` `&>`,  and `tee` ) seems to be able to capture it. However if I manually cut and paste the screen it's exactly what I want. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try to [enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) by adding the `--enable-logging` flag to the command line.

Also, although according to [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=729961) this is no longer necessary, it may be wise to add the `--disable-gpu` flag to prevent GPU errors from showing in the stdout.

The final command line should look like this:

```
chrome.exe --headless --enable-logging --disable-gpu --dump-dom "https://www.example.com/""
```

which returns the DOM of www.example.com/ on chromium 76.0.3809.87 succesfully.

Comment: Still relevant today (2023)